# Can I run a mediation analysis with a 3-level categorical predictor?

Tags: r, r-lavaan, mobile-ad-mediation

I want to run a mediation with a 3-level categorical predictor. Basically, I had participants assigned to 1 of 3 conditions for a vignette study (vignette type: control scenario, high mistreatment scenario, or low mistreatment scenario), I want to see whether vignette type predicts the dependent continuous variable through the continuous mediator.

I am new to R and am not sure how to best go about doing this analysis.

I believe I am supposed to effects code but I am not sure whether this is the proper approach.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.